# Installing a custom feature on a controller

Tags: maven, apache-karaf, opendaylight

I currently have a ODL controller running Beryllium SR4 and I am developing a network security application.

I have made a basic python rest client to interact with the controller and I found a feature im really interested in called "Controller Shield". After looking at the code it seems to not have any real functionality but id love to contribute and add functionality myself!

I am somewhat familiar with using maven to create archetypes to make developing apps a bit easier but one part im a little confused on is how I integrate my application or "feature" with a "full" controller. When I say "full" controller I mean it has L2 switching, openflow, dlux, restconf and some other basics.

In summary, what im trying to do is edit the code of an existing feature and implement it in a controller thats being used to control a network in mininet.  I have a mininet network and a controller thats working im just unsure of how to implement my changes to the features code. I can grab the projects code and edit it but testing it and using it is where im stuck.

Any help is appreciated! even if its just some resources on what im trying to do, that will be really helpful.

Comment: @rkosegi It appears Sodium doesent have any features I actually need, for example any type of L2 switching. I spent hours trying to get mininet to speak with my sodium release and it never worked.